# Quotient by product of prime ideals in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

In Allen Altman's Commutative Algebra, there is the affirmation that if $p$ is a prime ideal of $R$ and $R$ is a ring, then $(pR[x]+\langle x\rangle)/(pR[x]) \cong \langle x\rangle$. It seems intuitively plausible, but $pR[x]\cap\langle x\rangle \neq \emptyset,$ so I think it is not true.

Should it be $(pR[x]+\langle x\rangle)/(pR[x]) \cong (\langle x\rangle)/(p\langle x\rangle) \cong R/p[x]$?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: $pR[x] + <x>/pR[x]$ is the ideal generated by the image of $x$ in $R[x]/pR[x] \cong R/p [x]$. So, it is a prime ideal, but $R/pR$ is not.

Comment: @Youngsu You are right, it cannot be $R/pR$. I think it should be $R/p[x]$?

Comment: Note correct notation $$ \begin{align} \text{right: } & \langle x \rangle \\  \text{wrong:} & {}<x>{} \end{align} $$

Comment: @Youngsu : $\quad\uparrow \qquad$

Comment: That’s correct; $R/pR$ needs to be $R/pR[x]$.

Comment: I can't think of a good answer yet, so I'll note tediously that $R$ in this case must be a commutative ring with identity...and maybe an integral domain.

Comment: In any case, if my answer below was right, then you, @SantiagoEstupiñán, were almost on the right answer except for the very last step. I believe that $(\langle x\rangle)/(p\langle x\rangle)\not\cong (R/p)[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the isomorphism theorems for rings, we have that
$(S + I)/I \cong S/(S\cap I)$. In this case, we have $S = \langle x\rangle, I = pR[x]$, and hence we have
$(pR[x] + \langle x\rangle)/(pR[x]) \cong \langle x\rangle/ (\langle x\rangle \cap pR[x])$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems

The question now is--what is $\langle x\rangle \cap pR[x]$?

Elements of $pR[x]$ are of the form $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ip_ix^i$ where $a_i\in R$ and $p_i\in p$. And elements of $\langle x\rangle$ are of the form $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_ix^i$, i.e. there is no nonzero constant term in any polynomial in $\langle x\rangle$ except the zero polynomial. Then these two intersect exactly when $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_ix^i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ip_ix^i$ where $a_ip_i = b_i$, $a_i\in R$, and $p_i\in p$. (We should have been using $\mathfrak{p}$ for our notation this whole time...oh well.)

Hence in our quotient, we have that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ip_ix^i \equiv 0$ (where $a_i\in R, p_i\in p$). We are not quite left with just $(R/p)[x]$, however, because we still don't have polynomials of degree 0. I think it would be more like the ideal $\langle y\rangle\subset (R/p)[y]$. (I'm using another variable here just to make the distinction.)

Comment: The setup for the isomorphism theorem I'm referencing is that $S$ is a subring of some ring $R$ and $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: I realize now that my answer, if correct, means that Altman may have been right...but only if you abuse notation with $x$.

Comment: I think you are right, it should be the ideal $\langle y \rangle \subseteq (R/p)[y]$. Thank you very much for your help!